# In what sense are these two invariant measures on $SU(2)$ proportional?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, invariance, compact-manifolds, haar-measure

An element $g$ of $SU(2)$ is of the following form:
$$
g=\begin{bmatrix}
z_1  & z_2\\
-\bar{z}_2 & \bar{z}_1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $z_i$ are complex satisfying $|z_1|^2+|z_2|^2=1$. I can choose different parametrizations. The first one will be $z_1=|z_1|e^{i\phi},z_2=|z_2|e^{i\psi}$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ used to derive a real parametrization
\begin{align}
x&=\cos{\phi}\cos{\beta}\\
y&=\sin{\phi}\cos{\beta}\\
z&=\cos{\psi}\sin{\beta}\\
t&=\sin{\psi}\sin{\beta}
\end{align}
for $0\leq\phi,\psi\leq2\pi,0\leq\beta\leq\pi/2$. This is called the Hopf map (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-sphere) and the invariant measure (left and right since the group is compact) is $$d\mu=\sin{\beta}\cos{\beta}\ d\beta\ d\psi\ d\phi.$$

But I can use a different parametrization. I rewrite $g$ as
$$
g=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1+ix_2  & x_3+ix_4 \\
-x_3+ix_4 & x_1-ix_2 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and introduce
\begin{align}
x_1&=\cos{\theta}\\
x_2&=\sin{\theta}\cos{\phi}\\
x_3&=\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\cos{\psi}\\
x_4&=\sin{\theta}\sin{\phi}\sin{\psi}.
\end{align}
The invariant measure is now $$d\nu=\sin^2{\theta}\ d\theta\sin{\phi}\ d\phi\ d \psi.$$

QUESTION: An invariant measure on a Lie compact group is unique up to a multiplicative factor. In what sense is $d\mu$ proportional to $d\nu$? I must have misunderstood the uniqueness claim.

Comment: Have you tried writing them in the same coordinates?

Comment: Maybe you could explain what _you_ think it means for the measure to be unique up to a multiplicative factor.  That would clarify what you are missing.

Comment: I think I naively thought that there is a real $K$ where $d\mu=K d\nu$ for any parametrizations I choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the same measure is obviously going to look different if you write it in different coordinates.  For instance, Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is given by $dx\,dy$ in the usual coordinates but $r\,dr\,d\theta$ in polar coordinates.  To compare them you would need to write them using the same coordinates.

Another way to say this is that you have described two maps $F,G:\mathbb{R}^3\to SU(2)$ and found two invariant measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ on $SU(2)$ for which $F^*\mu$ and $G^*\nu$ do not differ by a constant factor. But that shouldn't be a surprise, because it is $\mu$ and $\nu$ themselves which differ by a constant factor, not their pullbacks $F^*\mu$ and $G^*\nu$ in two different coordinate systems.  What would be true is that $F^*\mu$ and $F^*\nu$ should differ by a constant factor--in other words, if you converted $d\nu$ into the same coordinates you used for your expression for $d\mu$, it would be the same up to a constant factor.

Comment: So is it essentially about the Jacobian, I see. Is there a coordinate-independent way of writing an invariant form for a given compact group ?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you mean by a "way of writing".  You could just give a name to the unique invariant form (normalized so the total measure is $1$, say).

Comment: Don't understand this comment but thanks for your time.